# What is the best way to Add database table primary keys to HTML file?

Tags: jsp, post, get, jstl, primary-key

I use JSTL loop to print out rows i got from a database. they have a primary key and i need this in my controller class to edit, remove the entries. How are these usually added to each entry? Do i use POST or GET to pass them to the controller. I'm quite new at programming,so examples and all the help i can get is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are usually to be added as a hidden input value. Use GET for requests which don't manipulate data (e.g. select for edit) and use POST for requests which manipulate data (e.g. create/update/delete).

E.g.

```
<table>
  <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
    <tr>
      <td>${product.id}</td>
      <td><c:out value="${product.name}" /></td>
      <td>
        <form action="products/edit" method="get">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${product.id}" />
          <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="products/delete" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${product.id}" />
          <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are they being passed from? If you're passing them from one server-side component to another server side component (e.g. a controller to a jsp page), then you should put them in the request object.

If they're being passed from something running in the browser to the server, then you would need some form of http communication.